# UILabel in my custom UITableViewCell doesn't change text properly

Tags: uitableview, uilabel

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` inside it I have a label that shows the ammount of licks , 
when i drawing the cell everything is fine , however when I'm trying to change the label text it overlaps on its self (and it is very sad tbh).

I tried to remove and add it again , also tried to set `needsDisplay` and it didn't help me  :(

here is my code :

in DrawLabel method

```
//we will start from the labels: licks and comments
_licksLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, self.frame.size.width, 40)];
[_licksLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[_dict objectForKey:@"loves"],LocalizedString(@"licks")]];

[_licksLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FONT_REGULAR size:15]];

[_licksLabel sizeToFit];
[_licksLabel setTextColor:UIColorFromRGB(grey4)];
[self addSubview:_licksLabel];
```

when I do want to change the label's text here in another method

```
- (void)meLike
{

if ([[_dict objectForKey:@"self_loved"]integerValue]>0)
{
  //  return;
}
[_licksLabel removeFromSuperview];
[FeedAPI loveFeedWithId:[_dict objectForKey:@"id"]];
[_dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKeyPath:@"self_loved"];
[_dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[[_dict objectForKey:@"loves"]integerValue]+1] forKeyPath:@"loves"];
[_licksLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[_dict objectForKey:@"loves"],LocalizedString(@"licks")]];
[_licksButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_lick_on.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self setNeedsDisplay];
[super setNeedsDisplay];
[self addSubview:_licksLabel];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find a little mess in your code. I Whould do like the following:

- Use interface builder to add a UITableViewCell prototype to your table
- assign (via interface builder) a reuse identifier (for example "cell")
- inside this UITableViewCell add a UILabel (via interface) and place it wherever you like
- assign a tag to the UILabel (for example 1)

After this setup you need to implement the table rows.

Here's an example

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell;

   cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   UILabel *name = (UILabel *) [self.tableView viewWithTag:1];
   name.text =  @"whateveryouwant;

   return cell;
}
```

Comment: I guess you didn't get the question , I have no problem to draw cells with text etc , however when I am trying to change the existing text the new texts comes over the existing and doesn't redraw it ... thus i tried several ways to work this arund :-/ 

your answer is more like: when uilables overlaps while scrolling which is not my case , also I disslike interface builder sorry

Comment: Perhaps I did not catch the problem but if the text overlaps the old one it seams like there are two UILabel one above the other. That is why I tried to describe the "classical" way of doing this thru interface builder. If you want to do it programmatically you are free to but double check that some code is not run twice. If you post the entire code I can give it a look otherwise I don't know how to help you.

Comment: It is okay friend ,I already solved it , the catch was in reloading table data ...Thanks for help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks for help to every1 i have solved the issue 
the solution was to reload the tableview data .